# Flash Components with Flex SDK

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

I am using the flex SDK to compile actionscript 3 classes into an swf.  Some components are not included with the SDK like the fl.controls components.

What options do I have for getting access to the flash components?  I've seen others mention  that I can export them to a swc file within Flash Pro, but I would rather not have to purchase Flash Pro to just use some components.  Is there any other manual way to perform this without purchasing or using Flash Pro?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use Flash Pro to do that.
here's what I do:

create an Fla and dump all the components on the timeline that you need.
you can then remove them from there (or leave them), it doesn't really matter, as long as you see them in the library. You can even move them directly into the library.

Then under publish options select flash only, and in the flash tab select the export to swc option.

now when you compile, even when using Ctrl-Enter the swc gets compiled.

The next step would be different for you, because I use flash develop (which is free) I copy the swc into my project's lib folder, and in the program I right-click on it and select add to library. done.

I don't know how you select the add to library in flex, but it is possible. Flash develop uses the flex compiler and it does it, and flash does it as-well. so czech the project setting for this option.

Answer (score 1):

You can get Free Flash Components here:
http://www.flashcomponents.net/components/free_flash_files.html?1=1&f=cprice&fv=0,0

They are not from Adobe but independent developers.

Here are set of 32 Flash UI Components for $99: http://www.flashloaded.com/flashcomponents/bitcomponentset/

I am pretty sure you have to purchase an Adobe Flash product to get the Adobe components. I used the components I got with CS4 for SDK development.

Comment: Thanks. Useful link.  I would still like to know about the fl.controls though.

Comment: I added a link to some UI components that are $99.