# Using old fonts in Flex SDK 4.5.1

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex

I recently started switching my project from Flex SDK 3.5 to 4.5.1, but my Label components aren't displaying anymore. I've determined that the problem is with my fonts; when I switch to the default font the text appears. I'm wondering, what exactly has changed in Flex SDK 4.5.1 for working with fonts?

---

original out-of-date question, here for reference:

Working in FDT, I have been using various components from the "fl" package under Flex SDK 3.5 by compiling them as a SWC as described in various places:

[Flash Components with Flex SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381575/flash-components-with-flex-sdk)

http://joshblog.net/2008/02/10/how-to-use-the-flash-cs3-component-set-in-a-flex-builder-actionscript-project/

http://www.actionscript-flash-guru.com/blog/14-flcontrols-not-found-how-do-i-import-the-fl-package

However, I just switched to the new SDK 4.5.1 and the labels aren't showing up. The code still compiles and runs fine, but no text is being displayed.

Does anyone know why a components SWC that was working before isn't anymore under the latest SDK, and how I should fix it? For example, do I need to recompile the SWC using the latest SDK somehow?

ADDITION: aha, I've figured out that the issue was with embedding fonts in the Label component; when I switch to the default font the text appears. I'm editing to the new question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aha, I found this article that explains it: http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=2555

Basically, Adobe changed the API for embedding fonts for no good reason, and now I need to have embedAsCFF="false"